# Orchard Placement file not hiding the Title Part

Tags: layout, orchardcms

In Orchard I have a placement.info file that should hide the Title part when I view an Author:

```xml
<Match ContentType="Author">
    <Place Parts_Title="-" />
    <Place Parts_Breadcrumbs="-" />
</Match>
```

Author is a custom content type I've created and the Breadcrumbs Part is a custom part.

The breadcrumbs part is hidden, but the title is still displayed. If I inspect it with Shape Tracing it is definitely `Parts_Title` I want to remove, but the content of my placement file doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that title is being rendered by that shape in your case?

Comment: The Shape Tracing module reports the Shape name as `Parts_Title` and the Active Template as `~/Core/Title/Views/Parts.Title.cshtml`. If I create an empty file called `Views\Parts\Title-Author.cshtml` the title is hidden. I just can't get it to work from inside `Placement.info`

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a whole of example to go on there, but it seems to me that this part is conflicting with the `Parts_Title` that ships with orchard.
Try extending the modifier in your placement as well as your shapes to something like:

```
Parts_MyModule_Title
```

This just adds some more clarity and can keep orchard from stepping all over itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar problem here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449507/orchard-1-8-unable-to-hide-metadata-published-date-from-custom-part-using-plac)

This is because your custom part's Placement.info was loaded first and Orchard Title part was loaded after that overriding it.

To solve it, in your custom part's Module.txt, put a dependence on **Title**. This will force Orchard Title to be loaded first before your custom part.