# Orchard 1.8 Unable to hide metadata (published date) from custom part using Placement.info

Tags: orchardcms

I have a Placement.info at the root of my custom part folder.

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-" />
    <Place Parts_MyCustomPart="Content:2" />
</Placement>
```

MyCustomPart displays fine. However, this doesn't hide the metadata. Using Shape Tracing, I managed to identify which Placement.info file was being loaded/processed that displays the metadata. It is `~/Core/Common/Placement.info` containing the rule

```
<Placement>
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <!-- Removed for brevity -->
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="Meta:2" />
    </Match>
</Placement>
```

I suspect that `MyCustomPart/Placement.info` was being loaded/processed first. And `~/Core/Common/Placement.info` is loaded after that effectively overriding **Parts_Common_Metadata** in the previous Placement.info.

Is there a way to define the order of which Placement.info is loaded/process first?

Comment: Use your theme to override placements in modules, you can also specify a priority for your module in the Module.txt, e.g. Priority: -1

This may make your module run before core stuff, but I'm not 100% about this. Using your theme would be the most reliable way to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a dependency on "Common" from your `module.txt` manifest file. This will let you take precedence.